# how to display image using its path

Tags: java, image, swing, path

i have a the path of an image in a string i want to display it on a jlabel using the path. please help me.

```
if(!ar.get(16).equals("empty")){
    String photo=(String)ar.get(16);

    System.out.println(photo);
    // if(!photo.equals(""))
    //  pic.setText(photo);

    Image image=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(photo);;
    ImageIcon img=new ImageIcon(image.getScaledInstance(view.jLabel5.getWidth(), view.jLabel5.getHeight(), 0));


    //JpegReader jrdr=new JpegReader();
    //view.jLabel5.setSize(img, image.getWidth());
    view.jLabel5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    view.jLabel5.setIcon(img);

}
```

Comment: What are the problems you are having?  If the `String` is the path and file name you should be able to use something like `ImageIO.read(new File(photo));`

Comment: how can i set it to a label then?

Comment: `ImageIcon` takes a `Image` reference, `BufferedImage` extends `Image`, so basically, the same way you are now.  Where does the image live?  Is it within the context of the application or on the file system some where?

Comment: the images are saved in a folder where inside application. i am getting the path an could print it on the label. but not the iamge

Comment: That sounds like they are embedded resources.  You need to use `getResource` to access them.  An example path would might help as well...

Comment: that too doesnt works sir.. i'll explain.. the image path is saved in the access database. using an arraylist am getting the path.in my application there is a search option and i get some details in a jtable. i select a data and on clicking a jbutton, an internal frame should be shown and the complete details of the selected data should display there. am getting all other data except the image. the image is saved in a folder namely images where the project is located.along with other folders like src,buil test etc..

Comment: The check that you can actually see the image file by using `System.out.println(photo + " exists " + new File(photo).exists());`, this should print `true` for a given photo IF the path and name are correct

Comment: nw i get this error...sun.awt.image.ImageFormatException: Unsupported color conversion request

Answer (score 3):

If the image is an embedded resources (ie lives within the application context/is bundled with the application Jar), then you need to use `getResource` to gain access to it..

`Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage` expects that the `String` passed to it is a file on the file system.

If the image is embedded, then you will need to use something more like...

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource(photo))
```

To load it.

If the image is being loaded from the file system, you could use

```
File file = new File(photo);
if (file.exists()) {
    // Attempt to load the image
} else {
    // Show error message.
}
```

Because of the way `Toolkit#getImage` works, it will not provide any details if the image fails to load for some reason.

Instead, you should be using `ImageIO`, which will throw an `IOException` if it was unable to load the image for some reason...

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(photo));
```

or

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(photo));
```

Depending on where the image is located.

Take a look at [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html).

You should also avoid calling `setPreferredSize` explicitly and simply allow `JLabel` to make it's own choices...

Answer (score 1):

Put the image file in the project. Under a seperate folder.

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/abc.jpg"));
JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(image, JLabel.CENTER);
```

If you want to load the image for any other location on your computer then,

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("C:/images/image.png");
JLabel imagelabel = new JLabel(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your paths are correct. If you `photo` string path is `"photo.jpeg"`, your path should look something like this

```
ProjectRoot
        photo.jpeg
        src
```

If you want to put the `photo.jpeg` in a directory `images`, you should use `"images/photo.jpeg"`

```
ProjectRoot
        images
            photo.jpeg
        src
```

This is considering you're using an IDE like Netbeans or Ecplise.