# How to get real path of a image in java

Tags: java, image, swing, awt, embedded-resource

```
private static void setToSystemTray(){
    //checking for support
    if (!SystemTray.isSupported())
    {
        System.out.println("System tray is not supported !!! ");
        return;
    }
    //get the systemTray of the system
    SystemTray systemTray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();



     //get default toolkit
    //Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    //get image 
    //Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("src/resources/busylogo.jpg");
    Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("./src/com/xxx/xxx/icons/Cloud.png");

    //popupmenu
    PopupMenu trayPopupMenu = new PopupMenu();

    //1t menuitem for popupmenu
    MenuItem action = new MenuItem("Action");
    action.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Action Clicked");
        }
    });
    trayPopupMenu.add(action);

    //2nd menuitem of popupmenu
    MenuItem close = new MenuItem("Close");
    close.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    trayPopupMenu.add(close);

    //setting tray icon
    TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "Backup System", trayPopupMenu);
    //adjust to default size as per system recommendation 
    trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);

    try
    {
        systemTray.add(trayIcon);
    } catch (AWTException awtException)
    {
        awtException.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("end of main");
}
```

This is the code I've used to get the image . This is working when I run the      java project in net beans . But this is not working when I execute the .jar file of the project .

This is the method which I used to get image for my purpose .

What's the mistake had I done in this code ?

Comment: For normal i use `ImageIO`s `read`: `Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("com/theace/backupsystem/icons/Cloud.png));`

Comment: Looks like there is some problem with file position of image in the jar file

Comment: @RehanZahoor: How do I fix it ?

Comment: place your image in folder src/com/theace/backupsystem/icons/Cloud.png relative to your class file before making jar file

Comment: Use `getClass().getResource("/com/xxx/xxx/icons/Cloud.png")` to get a `URL` reference to the file and preferably load it the image with `ImageIO.read`

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I am a new comer to the java so PLEASE give me a  support with your code .

Comment: [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html). No offense, this question gets asked three or four times a week :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Thank you very much and I'll try on this . Also I'll tell the result to you .

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29026776/system-tray-image-not-loading-java/29026936#29026936) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19921191/how-to-display-image-using-its-path/19921369#19921369)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Your suggestion is worked when I run the net beans . But I cannot achieve my task when I execute the .jar file .

Comment: You are placing your image file under src directory. Try creating a directory in say /classes directory of your net beans project. Then make jar file. Are you using NetBeans to make jar file? Netbeans would not include src directory in Jar, I think.

Comment: @RehanZahoor Embedded resources should included in the `src/` directory as the ant build system will pick them up

Comment: @Barrier Are you using Maven to build the project?

Comment: @MadProgrammer No I am not .

Comment: @Barrier So, assuming you're using the "default" ant build project, the images should be stored in the `src` directory, in the `/com/xxx/xxx/icons/` directory, then you using something like `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/com/xxx/xxx/icons/Cloud.png"));` to load them

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you very much it worked . Finally I solved my problem with your help .